# Callable<T> call() + Input parameters + Spring

Tags: java, multithreading, spring, jsp

I am struggling with the following:

1. The class is constructed through Spring
2. It implements the interface that consist of two methods (process, shutdown)
3. It also implements Callable

**The problem:** 
process() returns a Type and it is called inside the call(), the problem is that process has input parameters which call() signature doesn’t allow. So I referred to this question: [Is there a way to take an argument in a callable method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9992992/is-there-a-way-to-take-an-argument-in-a-callable-method), unfortunately that wouldn't work for me as my object constructed through Spring, process() gets called from the JSP and the input parameters are variable, depending on the user action.

**Will include some code for clarification, bellow:**

```
public class MyClass implements MyClassInterface, Callable<Results> {

   private String fileLocation;
   private final SMTPMailer smtpMalier;

   public MyClass(String fileLocation, SMTPMailer smtpMalier) {
      this.fileLocation = fileLocation;
      this.smtpMalier = smtpMalier;
   }

   public Results call() {
      // to return process(arg1, arg2) here, need to cater for input parameters
   }

   public Results process(String arg1, String arg2) {
      // does some proceeding, returns Results
   }

   public void shutdown() {
      // shut down implementation
   }
}
```

How can I go around this?

Comment: Would be better, if you share with us you use it. From other side why just don't call `process` since it is `public` method?

Comment: That is the current implementation, but I need MyClass to be runnable and to take input parameters as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer is, you can't. 
The contract of `Callable` is that it can perform an action *without* any input. 
If it needs parameters, it isn't `Callable`.

You need to consider how the code is called. I assume you have code like this:

```
AsyncTaskExecutor executor = ...;
MyClass theService = ...;
String foo = "apple", bar = "banana";
Future<Results> result = executor.submit(theService); // Needs foo and bar :(
```

The simple solution is, don't implement `Callable` in `MyClass`. It *isn't* callable, it needs some input parameters! Implement `Callable` where it makes sense instead, such as where you have all parameters:

```
AsyncTaskExecutor executor = ...;
MyClass theService = ...;
String foo = "apple", bar = "banana";
Future<Results> result = executor.submit(new Callable<Results>(){
    @Override public Results call(){
        return theService.process(foo, bar);
    }
});
// Or if you're on Java 8:
Future<Results> result = executor.submit(() -> theService.process(foo, bar);
```

If this is something that happens a lot and you really *really* want the class to provide you with `Callable`s, you could give it a factory method:

```
public class MyClass implements MyClassInterface {
   public Results process(String arg1, String arg2) {
      // does some proceeding, returns Results
   }
   public Callable<Results> bind(String arg1, String arg2) {
      return () -> process(arg1, arg2);
   }
   // Other methods omitted
}
```