# How to accept parameters in a new Callable instance passed as a function parameter

Tags: java, callback

I am new to Java and trying to pass a function as an argument that gets called when a certain event occurs. I came across Callable and found a few answers for similar problems but not this exactly.

Currently, my code is doing this

```
doSomething(new Callable<Void>() {
  public Void call() {
    System.out.println("callback called! ");
    return null;
  }
});
```

But I want this :

```
doSomething(new Callable<Void>() {
  public Void call(String foo) { // Want this function to accept parameters
    System.out.println("callback called with string " + foo);
    return null;
  }
});
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to take an argument in a callable method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9992992/is-there-a-way-to-take-an-argument-in-a-callable-method)

Comment: You can use Consumer instead Callable

Comment: @AnthonyCathers not really.

Comment: @SergeyAfinogenov i'll check

Answer (score 0):

The `java.util.function.Consumer` functional interface is exactly what you are looking for: accepts a single argument and returns no output.

You need to do something like:

```
    doSomething(new Consumer<String>() {
        @Override
        public void accept(String foo) {
            System.out.println("Consumer called with string " + foo);
        }
    });
```

Or even better, replace it with a lambda:

```
doSomething(foo -> System.out.println("Consumer called with string " + foo));
```

`doSomething` looks like this:

```
void doSomething(Consumer<String> stringConsumer) {
    stringConsumer.accept("Hello!");
}
```